# MongoDB: how to generate local date?

Tags: mongodb, date, localization

I generate a date in MongoDB shell:

```
var d = new Date();
d
```

but the date result doesn't match the time in my location

However, the same code in javascript, the `console.log(d)` can output the correct time in my location

Why? How can I generate my local time in MongoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB (including the console) will by default always generate and stores in UTC, however `ISODate`s do support a timezone offset ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC ) however you would need to manage the creation of that offset from your application.

As @CRUSADER mentions it is normally better to store the users offset within the row or even not at all, particularly if your user could be accessing from many locations with many different timezones. In this case it might actually be better to modify the dates within your client JavaScript to take care of the difference in timezone from where they are currently accessing the page.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the timezone (which you should store separately inside your application).

```
var myDate = new Date();
document.write(myDate.getTimezoneOffset());
```